# Puzzle Hunt First Clue

Tags: steganography

I'm part of a team hosting a puzzle hunt for middle school and high school students, and  I'm trying to get an idea of the difficulty of various puzzles.

If you do figure an answer, it would be nice if you could post the time it took you to figure it out as well.

---

Revelation 6:8

I looked, and behold, an ashen horfse; and he who sat on it had the name Death; and Haldes was following with him Authorityy was given to them over a fourth of the earth, to kill with sword and with faemine and with pestilence and by the wild bearsts of the earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the answer

> Flyer

Found by:

> Taking the extra letters found in various words
>  hor**f**se
>  Ha**l**des
>  Authority**y**
>  fa**e**mine
>  bea**r**sts

Took me:

> About 15 seconds

Comment: Ditto, except maybe fewer seconds. :\

Comment: As a side note, @Yllrauei, keep in mind that a puzzling site will have faster solve times than middle school and possibly high school students. The reason it took me about 15 seconds is merely because I was on my phone and had to scroll. But it is a good start to what I hope is a great puzzle hunt!

Comment: Also, @Yllrauei, don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer, if indeed I answered it correctly. And welcome to the site!